# Using Facebook Object in Multiple PHP Files

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a Facebook Application containing multiple PHP pages. If I reinstantiate Facebook objects in all the files I get an Error Invalid OAuth access token signature.

I have tried a number of alternatives, also the $facebook->getSession() function doesn't work in the new framework and is deprecated.

So I tried to keep the access token in the session and use the same access token in my next PHP file's Facebook object.

On my first page i Have instantiated my App using:

```
$app_id = "107684706025330";
$app_secret = "__SECRET__";
$my_url = "http://www.sentimentalcalligraphy.in/wp-content/then_n_now/";
$config = array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true,
);
session_start();
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $access_token;
$_SESSION['fob'] = $access_token;
```

On the next PHP file were I need to use the Facebook object for the second time:

```
$config = array(
'appId' => '107684706025330',
'secret' => '__SECRET__',
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$access_tocken = $_SESSION['fob'];
echo $access_token;
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

I still get an error that the access token is not valid. How am I supposed to use this. I need to use the following code in my second PHP file:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends','GET');
```

Thanking you in Advance,
Nasir

Comment: You should **never** post your `app_secret` anywhere.  With your `app_id` and `app_secret`, anyone could make calls to the API impersonating your application.

Comment: Are you missing the login part of OAuth 2.0 process? Or you omitted it?

Answer (score 1):

I have a some code for Facebook API. I want to share with you.

```
// App user account and password
$app_id = 'blabla';
$app_secret = 'blabla';
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
));
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
if(isset($_GET["code"])){ 
    // Get our app user feed
    $user_profile_feed = $facebook->api('/me');

    // Insert user id into users table while user login our app
    // We have to control user who inserted our users table after before
    $query_is_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ".$user_profile_feed['id']) or die("hata 1");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query_is_user);
    if($count == 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`(`user_id`) VALUES (".$user_profile_feed['id'].")") or die("hata 2");
        echo '<script language=Javascript>alert("Uygulamamiza Basariyla Giris Yaptiniz...");</script>';
    }

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                         . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . "http://apps.facebook.com/machine_learning/"
                         . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $_GET["code"];
    $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET access_token='$params[access_token]' WHERE user_id='$user_profile_feed[id]'") or die("hata 4");
}

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"
        ."client_id=262609310449368&"
        ."redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/machine_learning/&scope=read_stream";
```

Comment: While this might technically solve the OP's issue - you should **always** include an explanation of what you found to be the problem and how you went about solving it.   Posting a big block of code here is not good practice.  Keep trying to answer peoples questions!  That's **great!**  But you have to include some explanations too :)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your Reply.

However, being a novice I am not sure about the solution you are suggesting.

The main thing I am interested to know is in my second PHP file how do I get the Facebook object to execute codes such as 

    $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends','GET');

Because re-creating the facebook object in the new file is generating the error :Invalid OAuth access token signature